# Invoking SOAP API in old fashion

Tags: soap-api, integration, oauth2, connected-apps

I have registered in SF connected application, let say XY. This was done to accomplish SSO scenarios.

If there is integration on Partner API level as described, is it possible then to call from XY application SF web service API without OAuth 2.0 protocol ?
I want to call SOAP API by invoking login method with user name and password and then to use obtained session id in further communication with that API.

Why ?
We are having code (XY application) that is working perfectly on that way and I want just to add for SSO scenarios OAuth 2.0 protocol over connected app trust relationship.

Is that possible, or I have to move all of the calls to SF over OAuth. This mean to use access token instead of present session id.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its really possible to make authentication through oauth and then use normal login() and get session Id and make soap API calls .But provided you have obtained access token through Oauth you can simply make soap calls without login() method too.There is not much rework if you read the below article

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/03/oauth-and-the-soap-api.html

1) Implement one of the 6 flows supported by OAuth 2.0 and receive the access token, 'id' and other parameters from Force.com.

2) Make a GET request (passing in the access token as the OAuth authorization HTTP header) to the 'id' URI.

3) Insert the access token into the 'sessionID' SOAP header and make all subsequent API calls to the enterprise or partner SOAP endpoints returned by the previous step.

Comment: You mean the Access token will become the session ID? How can I test this with SOAP UI?