# Get access token from SOAP web method

Tags: soap-api, integration, oauth2

I have following situation. There has been defined partner trust between Salesforce and our XY web application. These are under OAuth 2.0 compliance. We have defined XY package with client key, secret and scopes. Package was registered in SF. XY is registered as connected app.

SF is calling XY SOAP API. Further in our SOAP API web method I want to call SF SOAP services to obtain user's details. To do that I need access token. How to accomplish this ? Because I am in web method I can not perform neither username-password flow (I do not know SF users credentials) nor web flow (I can not realize web redirections within web method). Which flow I have to use. Currently our partners are providing us (when calling our web method) session id. This session Id I can not use because our application should be in OAuth 2.0 trust.

What are suggestions here ? Is there any additional OAuth 2.0 flow that I can use in this use case ?

**UPDATE**
We can not use session id to call SF SOAP API because it was set in SF in connected app options App Access Settings : [image]

So any call with session id in SOAP message header will result with INVALID SESSION ID error from SF side. We had same issue with other OAuth flows and it did worked only for AccessToken. That issue is described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18123/invalid-session-id-this-session-is-not-valid-for-use-with-the-api-when-calling?rq=1)

Comment: Can you provide more details about this line: *This session Id I can not use because our application should be in OAuth 2.0 trust.*? Why you should not use session Id?

Comment: I believe that without **SF users credentials** or **web redirection** access token cannot be received.

Comment: Why SOAP? Why can you not use the REST API?

Comment: You will have to use an OAuth flow to get an access token.

Comment: @sfdcfox I need SOAP API because of existing implementation that we are just upgrading to OAuth 2.0.

Comment: @superfell It is obvious that we are talking about OAuth 2.0 flow

Comment: So, on a related question, I found out you just use the access token like a session ID. Just drop it in and go.

Comment: @sfdcfox In related question there was talk about different OAuth flow. In this one as you can see in description the major problem is how to obtain access token in our web service web method

Comment: Whomever is currently giving you a sessionId will need to get it via an OAUth flow instead of a SOAP login call.

Comment: @superfell Currelntyl customized SF app is calling our web method and give us session id. Is there a way to obtain access token on SF side directly ? As I know it is not possible ? Access token is only result of the handshake. Session id is only accessible on SF side. Correct me if I am wrong.